# How to interact with elements of the tab opened with GM_openInTab

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, greasemonkey-4, webgrease

I am opening a new tab using GM_openInTab inside my tampermonkey script, but I am not able to interact with the elements of this new tab using my code.

I simply want to click a button in the newly opened tab as soon as it opens and close it instantly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your script on the URL of the new tab you are opening as well (add an additional `@include` on top), you could make a distinction at the beginning of the script, like this:

```
if (location.href == oldurl){
  //open new tab
} else if (location.href == newurl){
  //click button, close
}
```